# What does it mean when an event handler is "registered"?

Tags: events, event-handling

What does it mean to register an event handler? What is the relation between define a handler and register a handler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An event handler is a function that gets called in response to an event.

Registering a handler connects the event to the handler, so that the code in the handler is executed when the event occurs. For example, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a way of doing this in jQuery.